# Animação individual de elementos

Tags: javascript

Olá.

Preciso de um script que gere um elemento `span` nos 20% iniciais ou finais da tela. Depois esse elemento precisa ter uma animação até o topo da tela dando *fadeout*.

A minha dificuldade está em fazer a animação individual dos elementos.
O tempo total da animação desde a criação até chegar ao topo é de 4 segundos. Tudo ocorre normalmente caso eu espere a animação de um elemento acabar para iniciar a próxima.

O problema esta quando inicio a animação do segundo elemento sem o primeiro ter finalizado. O primeiro elemento volta para a posição inicial e reinicia a animação.

Qualquer ajuda de como resolver esta situação eu agradeço.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3p0evqx/176/)

```js
let aux = 1;
let count = 0;
teste.onclick = function() {
  var html = '<span id="dot'+count+'" class="teste"></span>' 
    $('body').append(html);
  var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();
    if(aux == 1){
     var max = width * 0.20;
      var min = 1;
    } else {
     var max = width;
      var min = width * 0.8;
    }
    aux = aux * -1;
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max - min + 1) + min);
      $( "#dot"+count ).animate({
       left: x,
          bottom: '20px'
  }, 0, function() {
  });
 animate({
   duration:4000,
    timing: function(timeFraction) {
     return Math.pow(timeFraction, 5)
    },
    draw: function(progress) {
     $(".teste").css('bottom', progress * 80 + '%');
    }
  });
  $("#dot"+count).fadeOut(4500, function(){
    $(this).remove();
  })
  count++;
}



function animate({timing, draw, duration}){
 let start = performance.now();
  requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
    // timeFraction goes from 0 to 1
    let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
    if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

    // calculate the current animation state
    let progress = timing(timeFraction)

    draw(progress); // draw it

    if (timeFraction < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  
  });
}
```

```css
span {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="teste">
  Clique aqui
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: Cara seu erro é que vc está usando a classe .teste para setar um bottom, então todo elemento que vc cria vc coloca um bottom, vc pode colocar um count na classe como faz com o id que deve resolver! `$(".teste").css('bottom', progress * 80 + '%');` isso coloca bottom pra todo .teste que aparece, inclusive o que já estava animado que volta a ter o bottom inicial e não deveria

Comment: Confesso que li umas 5 vezes a pergunta e não consegui entender aonde quer chegar como resultado :D

Comment: Você quer criar um efeito de bolas subindo em posições randômicas no eixo X? Talvez fosse interessante apagar o javascript e fazer a animação só com CSS